# Angular: How to use multiple router-outlets?

Tags: angular, router, router-outlet

I have a component like this

**main page:**

```
<div> 
 <a routerLink="alpha"> Alpha </a>
 <a routerLink="beta"> Beta </a>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<footer></footer>
```

**beta template:**

```
<div>
 <a routerLink="/actual">actual</a>
 <a routerLink="/archive">archive</a>
<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**The possible scenario is:**
When you click BETA button on the home page, it brings up the router-outlet beta template in the home.
but the router-outlet in the beta template is empty. when I click on the links in the beta template, it will bring the component.

When the BETA link on the home page is clicked, the router-outlet in the beta page does not come up empty and the actual incoming component is clicked.

Comment: what exactly your question is? Please help us understand a bit.

Comment: This is enough for my english. I want = When the BETA link on the home page is clicked, the router-outlet in the beta page does not come up empty and the actual incoming component is clicked.

Comment: Hi @VolkanÇiloğlu, you're using Angulars `routerlink` directive wrong. The directives and routes need to be in brackets `[]`. e.g. `<a [routerLink]="['/actual']">actual</a>`

Comment: Also would you please provide your `routes` code? Probably in a file called `app-routing.module.ts` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, if you want some child route need to be activated when navigating to `beta`:

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'alpha', component: SomeComponentA},
      { path: 'beta',        
        component: SomeComponentB,
        children: [
           {
               path: 'actual',        
               component: SomeComponentBActual,
           },
           {
               path: 'archive',        
               component: SomeComponentBArchive,
           },
           // add
            {
               path: '',        
               redirectTo: 'actual', pathMatch: 'full',
           },
       ]           

  },         
   ];
```

So when you navigate to `beta`, it will redirect to it's child route.
[CODE EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-activate-child-route)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to do something like this. I will make this more useful by improving it a bit. Thank you for your help